# Changing environment in Kaggle? (Option Disabled)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dockerfile, ipython, kaggle

A kaggle (private) notebook of mine was created an year ago so it uses an environment (package versions) of the date when it was created. To use the latest package versions, there's an option to change Environment Preferences from within the `Edit` page of a notebook. But turns out, the option is disabled.

[image]

The only other way to get the latest package versions now is to upgrade them all manually by `pip` calls from within the notebook for each module. This was working fine until I required a newer version of `pandas`. You need to upgrade any module before importing in kaggle to use the upgraded version, otherwise it uses the old one. And `pandas` is one of the few libraries that is [preloaded](https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/99681#575703) with every notebook start, so an upgrade call to it still does not use the latest pandas. What can I do here? Any tips on how I can enable the environment preference option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem on Kaggle's end. They have rolled out a fix.

[More details](https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/271753#1511722)

If it happens again, create a thread on kaggle forum I guess, just like I did.